# Custom validation not setting rollback with false return

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that I want to make a condition to not create a new record if it returns false. My custom validation is not creating a rollback.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    validate :test # my custom validation


    private

    def test
        # condition to return false
        false
    end
end
```

Should I make any other previews configuration? Thank's.

Comment: What if, instead of `false`, the body of your `test` method is `errors.add_to_base('test')`?

Comment: it works if I put: " def test
    if record.first_name.size > 0
      false
    end
 end"

Comment: I guess that that it must contains some key words to be valid. When I put 'add_to_base' we have indeed a rollback but it is an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom validation should add an error to an array of errors for the model, for example:

```
def test
  errors[:base] << "This user is invalid because ..."
end
```

The method `valid?` checks if there are any errors in `errors` array. It does not care about return value from the custom validator.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed all this day!